# how to bind data to a edittext and spinner in android 4.0

Tags: android, mysql

I have create a android xml file with one edit text and one spinner. 
If I enter some input ie countryid in edit text the country of that id display in spinner.
If I select country from spinner then countryid display in edittext. please help me for same.

Comment: how is your data organized? some code would help

Comment: could you post the code that you tried so that we could help you if you did any wrong

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a circular dependency 
editext<->spinner

- **solution to it**

so in order to do so 
you have to implement `TextWatcher` interface in android so that whenever the data changes inside the editext it triggers the methods which you can see when you implement the TextWatcher interface.

for the spinner i would suggest doing the changing text work inside the `setOnItemSelectedListener` listener of spinner.

i hope it helps